# objective-c....deleting number number from my label by button

Tags: objective-c

i want to delete numbers individually by this button from my label
`NSMutableString *str=(NSMutableString *)label.text;`

`str=[str replaceCharacterInRange:NSMakeRange([str length]-1,1) withString:@""];`

error.....`"Void value not ignored as it ought to be"`

Answer (score 2):

You can't just cast an `NSString` as an `NSMutableString` and expect it to be mutable. You need to create a mutable string before you alter it.

```
NSMutableString *mutableString = [label.text mutableCopy];
[mutableString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([mutableString length] - 1, 1) withString:@""];
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. I can't make sense of what other problem you could be having.

Answer (score 1):

`replaceCharacterInRange:withString:` returns void since it is a mutable operation that modifies the string.

To fix your problem, the first thing you need to know is that you can not make a string mutable just by casting it as `NSMutableString` you need to use `mutableCopy`.

```
NSMutableString *str= [label.text mutableCopy];

//Now the next thing do not assign str
[str replaceCharacterInRange:NSMakeRange([str length]-1,1) withString:@""];

...
//And finally when you are done if you are not using ARC 
///then you need to release the string since you called `mutableCopy`.
[str release];
```

Answer (score 0):

use deleteCharactersInRange:

```
[str deleteCharacterInRange:NSMakeRange([str length]-1,1) ])]
```